# WithMaxRetry Graph API Timespan and MaxRetry

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

As per the screenshot below. There are 2 WithMaxRetry for Graph API SDK, one with timespan and the other one is with integer count.  The problem is I need to set max retry with a combination of timespan and times, ie: I would like to retry 3 times after every 1 second. Any Idea how to implement the code?  Would this code below works accordingly?

```
graphClient
  .Users["myuser@mydomain.com"]
  .MailFolders["myemailFOlder"]
  .Messages
  .Request()
  .WithMaxRetry(3)
  .WithMaxRetry(new TimeSpan(1))
  .Filter("myEmailFilter")
  .GetAsync()
```

[BaseRequestExtensions.WithMaxRetry Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.baserequestextensions.withmaxretry?view=graph-core-dotnet)

`WithMaxRetry<T>(T, Int32)`

> Sets the maximum number of retries to the default Retry Middleware
> Handler for this request. This only works with the default Retry
> Middleware Handler. If you use a custom Retry Middleware Handler, you
> have to handle it's retrieval in your implementation.

`WithMaxRetry<T>(T, TimeSpan)`

> Sets the maximum time for request retries to the default Retry
> Middleware Handler for this request. This only works with the default
> Retry Middleware Handler. If you use a custom Retry Middleware
> Handler, you have to handle it's retrieval in your implementation.

Comment: Don't paste images of code, and definitely don't paste images of library code, when there is documentation available

Answer (score 2):

Your only problem is the `Timespan`

1 Second Timespan example

```
// ... Use days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

Or [TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int seconds)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_FromSeconds_System_Double_)

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
```

So your code becomes:

```
graphClient
  .Users["myuser@mydomain.com"]
  .MailFolders["myemailFOlder"]
  .Messages
  .Request()
  .WithMaxRetry(3)
  .WithMaxRetry(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0))
  .Filter("myEmailFilter")
  .GetAsync()
```